# Can not connect to hidden wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, connection

I am unable to connect to a hidden wireless network on my ThinkPad running Ubuntu 14.04.

The login credentials are definitely correct and work on both an old iPad-Tablet and an Android phone, however when entering the hidden SSID and password on my Ubuntu laptop, the Wifi-Icon will flash for a few seconds and then show an error message, stating that no network connection has been established, without a password-prompt or any other response.

I am currently re-installing my laptop and have had this problem on Xubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 16.04 and now on Ubuntu 14.04 (because I read that 16.04 in particular appears to have bugs regarding hidden wireless networks).

I can connect to the guest-network established by the same Wifi-Router without any issues, just connecting to the private hidden network on my laptop does not work.

Is there anything that I can try to solve this?

Comment: Why hide the network if it is WPA2 secured?  Hiding it doesn't help security

Comment: Well, at first I was a bit critical when reading your comment, thinking that it doesn't offer advice or a solution to the problem at all. Then, it made me look into the whole "hidden network" problem and indeed, you are right. Although that still doesn't really explain the issue, I will now unhide my network as it is not only useless for security purposes, but even counter-productive, since the devices will constantly broadcast the SSID and their names in search of the hidden network when being set to auto-connect. Thanks for notifying.